# How to work around Entity Framework date time type bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-functions

I want to get the all the monthly expired products, here is the query for that:

```
_customerProductsRepository
    .Where(
        d =>
        !d.ReleaseDate.HasValue &&
        EntityFunctions.AddMonths(d.RenewalDate ?? d.AcquireDate, 1) < now)
    .ToArray();
```

**AcquireDate** is the first purchase of the product and **RenewalDate** is the last renewal of the product.

For some reason it translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[CustomerDidId] AS [CustomerDidId],
[Extent1].[DidNumber] AS [DidNumber],
[Extent1].[CountryId] AS [CountryId],
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId],
[Extent1].[AcquireDate] AS [AcquireDate],
[Extent1].[ReleaseDate] AS [ReleaseDate],
[Extent1].[RenewalDate] AS [RenewalDate],
[Extent1].[RenewalNotificationDate] AS [RenewalNotificationDate]
FROM [dbo].[CustomerDids] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ReleaseDate] IS NULL) AND ((DATEADD (month, 1, [Extent1].[Rene
walDate])) < @p__linq__0)
```

There should be a case statement referring to the '??' sign, instead - it completely removed AcquireDate column.

How can I walk-around it?

Comment: Have you configured the property `RenewalDate` as required?

Comment: have you tried to change `??` to `? :` operator?

Comment: Note that the actual problem here is that the null coalescing operator `??` is not being handled as you expect and being translated into a TSQL `case`. It's not really related to the `DateTime` type at all, per se. See my answer.

Comment: @Eranga, you're absolutely right! for some reason it was required!! I've removed it and now it's working fine. Please write that as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @EranBetzalel gave the comment as an answer. glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the property `RenewalDate` as required. Hence EF will optimize the query by evaluating the result of the "if" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this way:

```
_customerProductsRepository
    .Where(
        d =>
        !d.ReleaseDate.HasValue &&
        (d.RenewalDate.HasValue ? 
              EntityFunctions.AddMonths(d.RenewalDate.Value, 1) < now) :
              EntityFunctions.AddMonths(d.AcquireDate, 1) < now))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the ternary operator will fare any better than the null coalescing operator at being translated to TSQL here. If it does,then this answer should work great and is more concise than mine.

Comment: Didn't work, my WHERE is now this:
WHERE ([Extent1].[ReleaseDate] IS NULL) AND ((CASE WHEN ((DATEADD (month, 1, [Ex
tent1].[RenewalDate])) < @p__linq__0) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((DATEADD (
month, 1, [Extent1].[RenewalDate])) < @p__linq__0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END) = 1
)

Answer (score 0):

One scenario if you can't get this to work as IQueryable, get all the data as an IEnumerable (call [asEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)) and then filter out via the date methods you specify.

Comment: Of course you can do that, but that defeats the purpose in my case.